# d3 hierarchical bar chart with negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the hierarchical barchart in d3 (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663).

The example as is does not handle negative values (the range is set to start at 0). I modified it so that it would but it is a bit ugly. If my minimum value is -5, then a value of 2 will have a bar from -5 to 2.

I would like something like this, where the axis starts at 0:
https://gist.github.com/mbostock/2368837

I've modified a few of the obvious things like fixing the domains, adding absolute values where needed. However, I think the issue is in my bar function. The x() function doesn't seem to be returning the right things. For example when I set .attr("x",x(0)), the bar doesn't start at 0.

Could someone point me into the right direction of how I could apply that to the hierarchical example?

Comment: What you're describing **should** work —— as long as you make sure to set both `attr('x',...)` and `attr('width',...)` just like the gist shows, AND as long as you're properly setting the x domain from some negative value to some positive value (you can hard code the domain at first, to eliminate mistakes). BTW, I assume your data is not being transformed by a partition layout like the one that's used in mbostocks hierarchical barchart, because there's no way that layout would ever generate negative values.

Comment: @meetamit last comment is pertinent. The hierarchical bar chart is a strange bird. Yes, ultimately, it can be considered a bar chart but, conceptually, it is not there to show frequency of values, ranging from negative to positive. It is really about property of items within a container. Note how Mike's example talks about file sizes within a folder. Also, note how Mike bills it as an alternative representation to a partition layout. So, I believe that conceptually and practically, it is not a good fit to attempt to show negative values via this chart.

Comment: @meetamit thanks, those were the main things I've looked at and changed.Something is still missing so I will look closer.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes point well taken. I have underlying data that fits the criteria. However, what I'm try to do is now consider differences between two of these things. So consider a file size breakdown. Then consider the same thing for a different system (same files/folders but different sizes). So at each level I want to show where the size differences are. The positive/negative is really just indicating which system is bigger. Maybe I can better do this with color.

Comment: Yes, a hierarchical *grouped* bar chart would come handy :)